# In PHP how can I call a function with the same variables that were passed to it?

Tags: php, arrays, list, function

If I have a two functions, I know I can call `function two` from `function one` in this way:

```
function one($a,$b,$c,$d)
{
    two($a,$b,$c,$d);

}
```

But is it possible to do it in a more dynamic way, something like this?

```
function one($a,$b,$c,$d)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    two(list($args));

}
```

Comment: You want to do this without using `func_get_args()` in `two`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and you're already halfway there ;). Use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

```
function one($a,$b,$c,$d) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array('two', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to do this:

```
function one($a,$b,$c,$d) 
{ 
    call_user_func_array('two', func_get_args());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [`call_user_func_array`](http://fr.php.net/call_user_func_array) should help you to call your two function with parameters being in an array.

Second, [`func_get_args`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) should give the the arguments in a clean array, so to summarize:

```
function one($a, $b, $c, $d) 
{
   call_user_func_array('two', func_get_args());
}
```